# CQ5 Multiselect component

Tags: extjs, aem

Lately, I found there is no **"Multiselect" component in cq5**.
I am looking if someone could guide me or share something to create a "Multiselect component" that would be great.

xtype - 'selection' - select dropdown allows only to select one item.
I need to select multiple items.

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the "selection" xtype as a checkbox:

```
type="checkbox"
xtype="selection"
```

See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection for all the config options.  It states that

> The type of the selection. One of "checkbox", "radio", "select" or
>   "combobox". "checkbox" is the only type that supports mulitple values

Comment: Yes, I tried 'checkbox' option but it is not a dropdown, rather than it displays all options with a checkbox beside the each option.

Comment: Right.  There isn't a dropdown that allows multi-select, so you'd need to build you own if you need that display.  But functionally, multiple checkboxes accomplishes the same thing as a multi-select dropdown.